# Node JS Promise.all and forEach in nested Array

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, promise

In a Node app with typescript, i need to iterate through a array and i call  an asynchronous function inside the loop to get informations about the related items for each item in the array. The function is called for each related item to get its title in relatedItems array.

I'm able to retrieve promises for the 2nd level array (relatedItems) but not sure how to implement a then once top level finishes as well.

How to reach my goal with promise.all.

```
var Inputarray = [
    {   Category: "cat1"
        relatedItems: [
            {id: "1"},
            {id: "2"},
            {id: "3"}
        ]
    },
    {
        Category: "cat2"
        relatedItems: [
            {id: "1"},
            {id: "2"},
            {id: "3"}
        ]
    }
];


var wantedresult= [
    {   Category: "cat1"
        relatedItems: [
            {Title: "xxx"},
            {Title: "yyy"},
            {Title: "zzz"}
        ]
    },
    {
        Category: "cat2"
        relatedItems: [
            {Title: "ttt"},
            {Title: "kkk"},
            {Title: "mmm"}
        ]
    }
];


private GetAllRelattedItems(data: IListItem[]): any{  


      let rendredItems: RelatedItem[] = new Array();



              data.forEach(item => {


                  let relatedItemsinfos : relatedItemInfos[]=item.Children;

                     let localTab:relatedItem[]=new Array();

                      let newItem = {
                              Category:item.Category,              
                              Children: []           
                      };

                    var promises = [];
                    relatedItemsinfos.forEach(relatedItemsInfositem =>{
                        promises.push(this.GetRelatedItem(relatedItemsInfositem.WebId,relatedItemsInfositem.ListId,relatedItemsInfositem.ItemId));
                    });
                     Promise.all(promises).then(function(response) {

                        response.forEach(obj=>{
                          let newNode: relatedItem ={
                            Title :Obj.Title,

                          };

                          newItem.Children.push(newNode);

                        });


                        rendredItems.push(newItem);


                    });


              });

} 


private  GetRelatedItem(id:string) : Promise<relatedItem> {

  return new Promise((resolve) => {

    pnp.sp.site.openWeb()
    .then(web => {
    //this.getWeb()
    //.then((web) => {

      return web.web.lists.getList().get();     //w.web.lists.getById("").get().then(r => {
    })
    .then((list) => {
      return this.getItem(list,id);
    })
    .then((item) => {

      resolve(item);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Promise.all` at the top level and return the promise for each item in the data array:

```
private GetAllRelattedItems(data: IListItem[]): any {
  //..
  let allData = data.map(item => {
    //..
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function (response) {
      //..
    });
  });
  Promise.all(allData).then (_=> { /* After all data is retrieved */})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Typescript a better approach would be to take advantage of `async/await` to make the code more readable:

```
private async GetAllRelattedItems(data: IListItem[]): Promise<RendredItem[]> {
  let allData = data.map(async item => {
    let relatedItemsinfos: relatedItemInfos[] = item.Children;

    let localTab: relatedItem[] = new Array();

    let newItem = {
      Category: item.Category,
      Children: []
    };

    var response = await Promise.all(relatedItemsinfos.map(relatedItemsInfositem => {
      return this.GetRelatedItem(relatedItemsInfositem.WebId);
    }));

    newItem.Children = response.map(entry => ({
        Title: entry.value[0].Title,
        FileLeafRef: entry.value[0].FileLeafRef,
        Modified: entry.value[0].Modified,
        FileRef: entry.value[0].FileRef,
        FieldValuesAsText: {
          FileRef: entry.value[0].FileRef,
        }
    }));
    return newItem;

  });
  var result = await Promise.all(allData);
  // After all results are done
  return result
}

private async GetRelatedItem(id: string): Promise<{ value: relatedItem[] }> {
    const web = await pnp.sp.site.openWeb()
    const list = await web.web.lists.getList().get();     //w.web.lists.getById("").get().then(r => {
    return await this.getItem(list,id);
}

// Placeholder
public getItem(list: any[], id: string ): Promise<{ value: relatedItem[] }>{
  return Promise.resolve({
    value : []
  });
}
```

**Note** I guessed some of the types based on usage, you should review to make sure they are correct.

Comment: using async and await i get the result.Thanks

Comment: @user9019334 don't forget to mark as answered and up-vote if it was useful :)

Comment: I would like to call another async function in my getItem function .  The function take as paramater the item title and return the item size so it must wait for getitem to be executed to get the title of each item. How can i modify my code with await/async to add this function. the goal is to obtain a final ouput item model  : item {title:"";modified:"";itemsize:"";}.

Comment: If you mark the `getItem` function as `async` you can just use `await otherFunction("Title")` if you post the code I may be able to help you a bit more. Don't forget to up-vote and mark as answered !

Comment: private GetItemSize(title: string): Promise<relatedItem>{ 
   Let url:string ; // simple function of title
   // Retrieves item size with rest async the response is the size.

   return this.context.spHttpClient.get(url,SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: Response)=>{

        return response.json(); 

    }); 

  }  the rest call return only the size information but i would like to return a related item model with size property.

Comment: `private async GetItemSize(title: string): Promise<relatedItem>{ 
    let url:string ; 
    let response‌​ = await this.context.spHttpClient.get(url ,SPHttpClient.configuration‌​s.v1);
    /* Asuming the json has the shape of relatedItem */
    return <relatedItem>response.json();
  }`

Comment: the rest call return only the size as a number so The json does not have the shape of relatedItem and i would like to return a final output relatedItem that contain size information. How can i reach my goal ?

Comment: still not get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
private async GetAllRelattedItems(data: IListItem[]): Promise<RendredItem[]> {

    let allData = data.map(async item => {

      let relatedItemsinfos: relatedItemInfos[] = item.Children;

      let localTab: relatedItem[] = new Array();

      let newItem = {
        Category: item.Category,
        Children: []
      };

      var response = await Promise.all(relatedItemsinfos.map(relatedItemsInfositem => {
        return this.GetRelatedItem(relatedItemsInfositem);
      }));

      newItem.Children = response.map(entry => ({
          Title: entry.value[0].Title,
          FileLeafRef: entry.value[0].FileLeafRef,
          Modified: entry.value[0].Modified,
          FileRef: entry.value[0].FileRef,
          FieldValuesAsText: {
            FileRef: entry.value[0].FileRef,
          }
      }));
      return newItem;

    });
    var result = await Promise.all(allData);
    // After all results are done
    return result
  }



private async  GetRelatedItem(relatedItemsInfositem) : Promise<any> {
  const web = await pnp.sp.site.openWebById(relatedItemsInfositem.WebId);
  const list = await web.web.lists.getById(relatedItemsInfositem.ListId).get();     
  return await this.getItem(list,relatedItemsInfositem.ItemId);
  // here i would like to call GetItemSize that is async and that take return the size as a number but i would like to return the whole item model 
}

public getItem(list: any, itemId: string): Promise<any>{
  let url: string;
  if(list.ParentWebUrl !='/'){
    url= list.ParentWebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+list.Title+"')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,Title,File/ServerRelativeUrl,Modified,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef&$expand=File&$expand=FieldValuesAsText&$filter=Id eq "+itemId; 

  }
  else url="/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+list.Title+"')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,Title,File/ServerRelativeUrl,Modified,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef&$expand=FieldValuesAsText&$expand=File&$filter=Id eq "+itemId;

  return this.context.spHttpClient.get(url,SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: Response)=>{  
    return response.json();  
  });  


}

private async GetItemSize(title: string): Promise<relatedItem>{ 
let url:string ; 
let response‌​ = await this.context.spHttpClient.get(url ,SPHttpClient.configuration‌​s.v1); 
// Asuming the json has the shape of relatedItem : Here the response is just a number and not shaped RelatedItem the goal is to return the whole relatedItem with size information.
   return <relatedItem>response.json(); }
```